# Promise, then() is not executing after "resolve" in superagent

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, superagent

I am a beginner in javascript and nodejs, I have created an API call to verify access token from Facebook. I am using superagent to make api calls.

After calling resolve(..) inside Promise, catch statement is getting executed

Here is the code - https://pastebin.com/eyESugXL

**Entry point** of code -

```
route.post('/sign_up_mobile')
```

Output -

```
222
POST /api/sign_up_mobile 500 792.110 ms - 40
```

**Console log -**

```
app is started at PORT : 8001
monogo db connected at port :27017
222
POST /api/sign_up_mobile 500 567.852 ms - 40
```

**Rest api**

url - http://localhost:8001/api/sign_up_mobile

**Headers**

```
x-access-token:EAANjyYzErxgBADukUaJR09k8ZAwKY81j768KdtlyYROTWv7sS022ZA8jF8MzNojX9UR6aBuOuGfk0KPys452HZCdFuy3lv2zXQ6QC4NDMwpNCBasChqZA9iFJRB2rR4vownTfCUZCmSNANW1Q6TjIpjcDqREIBHd2ZBNsxCsYr5GwgC8wZCCn1ZBTAh08Gp58Q4ZD
Content-Type:application/json
```

**payload** -

```
{
"from":"facebook",
"email":"rahul@gmail.com"
}
```

**Rest api response** -

```
{
"message": "Unauthorised from facebook"
}
```

**Full code** for this file - 
url - https://pastebin.com/ek4Y33jA

Comment: Where is the code for `doAfterVerification`?

Comment: I have edited the code snippet. Please check the url is also changed.. url - https://pastebin.com/eyESugXL

Comment: doAfterVerification does not matter that much, the code is still going to catch statement

Comment: Could you log the error and post that output?

Comment: Question is updated. with console logs and rest api out put

Comment: This is very stupid of me. I logged the error inside the catch statement and a variable 'v' was undefined inside then() statement. Sorry everyone I took your time